# Catch save (Ctrl/Cmd+S) keyboard shortcut in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there a cross-browser way or ***cross browser solution*** to capture the "Save" keyboard shortcut in the browser? For example, in GMail if you use CMD + S it will save the email and not prompt the browser to download the webpage (default behavior). I would rather use a cross browser solution than add event listeners and write it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cross browser solution is to check out [keycode.js](https://github.com/nostrademons/keycode.js). Less hassle to worry about looking for browser caveats and such.

I know it's old, but it still works. You can check out its [demo](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/js_keycode/test_keycode.html) too!

Looking at the demo, and the header comments in the .js, something like this?

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event
    var k = KeyCode.translate_event(e);
    if( k.ctrl && !k.alt && !k.shift && k.code == 83 ) //83 is the code for s
        save(); //Magic function
    if(e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how to use it? I just want to listen to the Save (CTRL+CMD+S) event.

Comment: I'm not familiar, but I updated my answer. Partially tested, you may or may not want the `preventDefault` based on your needs.